# What MOSFET circuit replaces a diode in a 48V 40A escooter?

Tags: mosfet, comparator, conversion

I want to use a 1kW generator and convert my eScooter to a hybrid.

The scooter uses a 48V SLA battery bank of 4x22Ah SLA batteries in series.

I used a transformer from a 1200W microwave oven and rewired the secondary to give me 54V.

Made a bridge rectifiers by placing 20x2A 100V diodes in parallel for a total of 80 diodes (didn't have a big diode).

I also series/paralleled 1000uF@16V caps to give me 8000uF, @96V.

My scooter uses 40 Amps to start moving and depending on the speed switch, will draw 25A (medium speed) or 30A (high speed).

If I connect an 80A diode from the generator's output to the battery, it should prevent the back feed from when I apply the brakes and the regeneration kicks in. Which is about 65-70V at 30A.

The diode will not work as there is too much power lose.
I need a circuit that will use MOSFETs to do the job.

Ideally, the circuit will chose the higher voltage source and prevent the regenerative current to flow back into the generator part of the source.

Can anyone help me?

More info on request.

Thanks.

Comment: I can post pictures if this system allows. Not sure if I can, being my first time on this site. This system has a mind of its own. Took out my "Hi all" at the beginning!

Comment: Search for "MOSFET ideal diode".

Comment: If by "rewired" you mean rewound the transformer yourself, I suddenly got back some hope for the new generation of facebook-double-clicking youngsters. If you actually meant rewired, I'm deeply concerned about your and your transformers saftey.

Comment: Also,  96v at 8000uf is about 288 of the 1000uf @16v capacitors.  You sure you counted right?

Comment: I found the solution: LTC4357 with CSD19535KTTT MOSFETS. Thanks for the clue JimmyB.